# Database design solution

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am having the following case:
There is entity 'Master_Entity'. This entity has properties as name, type, duration etc. There are other two type of entities 'Entity' and 'Sub-Entity'. There are identical as the 'Master_Entity' (They have absolutely the same properties).

At the end the 'Master_Entity' should hold a collection of 'Entity' and 'Entity' should hold a collection of 'Sub-Entity'. The tricky part is that records of type 'Entity' can be part of different 'Master_Entity' (same for 'Sub-Entity'), but they can have different values for duration for example. How can achieve such modularity?

Here I came up with, but it's not quite do the work. May you guys help me with this.

[image]

Edit: Imagine this as some sort of a work tracker. For example you have a 'Create PHP App' (Master entity). This entity contains duration of how long it will take to finish this job. In addition it contains a entity 'Writing Code' (Entity) and this one can be divided to 'Writing Http Client' (Sub-Entity) which has duration property which is specific for this job.

On other side you might have other job: 'Create an Java App' (Master Entity) which will contain the same 'Writing Code' entity, but with duration which will have different value, because of the context of the Application you are building.

I want to have a single record 'Writing Code', but the duration value that it have should be different for every job it's assigned to. How can achieve that with creating a minimum duplicating records of type 'Entity'?

Comment: What do you mean with "*but it's not quite do the work*"? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Perhaps some sample data and expected results would help me understand what your issue is. And stop using that horrible ID as identifier name, I can't tell what you are using as the join pk/FK relationships from your diagram. Id as a name is a very bad SQL antipattern.

Comment: @HLGEM ID is a great column name for a PK as long as every FK is TargetTableNameID.

Comment: Added more info to the post

Comment: What you have here is [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: @YB, no it is not. It makes it harder to write complex reporting queries. IT makes it far more likely that there will be a code error in a join  and eliminates the ability to correctly use the USING keyword in a join if your database allows that. Unfortunately it will pass the syntax check and let you use USING, but you will be joining on the wrong thing. So the potential for data integrity issues is too high to ever use ID. It should NEVER be used.

Comment: @HLGEM it would be nice if you could link to some authoritative source for your assertion.  I have used ID for 15 years and have never run into any issues.  Some folks that I have worked with thought it was a bad practice but after using it for a while decided they liked it much better.  An example to be clear my clients table has ID as primary key and any foreign key in other tables has ClientID.  So a join would be Clients.ID = SomeTable.ClientID.  If after all this time, I am doing something very bad I would love a chance to learn a better way.

Comment: @HLGEM If table names (including CTEs) are mnemonic and adequate then fully qualified identifiers can be used throughout the queries thus making it easier to split and debug them.

Comment: @Vasil  I usually have a 'type' table to hold 'repeated values'.  So Writing code would exist once in this table and your 'Create App' record would have a link to 'Writing Code' type and a duration.

Comment: @HLGEM, that's an interesting take on PK naming. DO you have an article I could read more about it? As a professional developer for over a decade myself, I've used both methods and vastly prefer ID over TableId. I do as JoeC describes and find it quite easy and I've never seen anyone I've worked with get their join wrong due to ambiguity.

Comment: Probably we should move the ID discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933803/database-design-primary-key-naming-conventions).

Comment: suggest you read, https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1492708537&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=sqlantipatterns

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something like these 3 tables will work for you:

```
Entity
* Id
* Name
* Type

EntityGroup
* Id
* Name
* ParentEntityGroupId
* ParentEntityId    

EntityRelationship
* Id
* EntityId
* ParentEntityId
* EntityGroupId
```

With this structure, you can have an Entity be a member of a Group, or a solo Child of another Entity. You can also have a Group be a Child of an Entity, or even a Child of another Group. Without knowing specifics of your data, it's hard to know what you might need, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this approach

Answer (score 0):

From what you have said, it seems that you don't need EAV at all because you don't have different properties for each item just different values.  And thus you should not be using it.

What you need is a combination of lookup tables and then tables that address the actual tracking history of the work. **This is because this is time sensitive data.** The tasks at the time the projects was created may be substantially different than the tasks associated with that task group two years from now, but you need to record the tasks at the the time of creation). Note that this is not denormalizing, it is creating a picture of data in time. The real duration always goes to teh project not ever to the Task.  In the task, you can have a suggested duration to use as a starting point.  I used a similar design (with far more fields of course) to design a database for building sales proposals for technical-hardware related projects. The real key here is to recognize what data needs to be stored as a point time time and what is lookup data used to build the final project data. If someone adds a new task to the "Create a Java App" group, you don't want to change details about projects already completed or in work, only new projects.

So you need:

```
Task group
  Task Group ID
  Task Group Name 

Task
  TaskID
  Task Name
  SuggestedDuration (can be null if you have tasks that are always different
                     but filled in for tasks that usually have a similar duration)

Task_Taskgroup
    TaskID
    TaskGroupID

Project
    ProjectID
    ProjectName
    TaskGroupID

ProjectTask (should be filled in automatically when the task group is 
             chosen for the project)
    ProjectID
    Task ID
    EstimatedDuration (fills in the default value, but can be changed 
                       by the person creating the work project)
    ActualDuration (Field in after the task is done, can be used by an 
                    analyst to create more reflective task default duration values)
```

Of course each of these tables may have other fields depending on the need.